# Exclude folder in ASPNETCORE project from VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP.NET CORE project, and of course I don't want to use it to build the typescript.  I've setup a 'broccoli' folder with a nice build and a browser-sync server.  The problem is that visual studio hangs when loading a project.

broccoli generates a `tmp` directory with lots of other directories for the build trees.  Sometimes these get left over when the browser-sync task doesn't shut down cleanly.  This causes Visual Studio 2015 to freeze when loading the project.

Is there a way to tell VS2015 to ignore my broccoli folder completely?  Attempts:

1 - hiding the folder (`attr broccoli +h`)

2 - adding to exclude in project.json "buildOptions/compile" and/or "embed":

```
 "buildOptions": {
   "emitEntryPoint": true,
   "preserveCompilationContext": true,
   "compile": {
     "exclude": [ "node_modules", "obj", "broccoli", "bin", "src" ]
   },
   "embed": {
     "exclude": [ "node_modules", "obj", "broccoli", "bin", "src" ]
   }
 },
```

3 - Adding to exclude in project.json (says deprecated, use within compile or embed"

4 - Adding this to my xproj:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

5 - Adding to exclude in `tsconfig.json` along with everything else I can think of because I ONLY want to do typescript compilation using broccoli in my subdirectory:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings",
  "typings.d.ts",
  "broccoli",
  "wwwroot",
  "src"
]
```

Is there any way to get VS2015 to just ignore a folder completely in one of these projects?  The problem is that when the project loads vs is looking through all those directories.  I can tell because when it takes a long time and I go to the command line and delete everything under 'broccoli/tmp', some of the files still show up in visual studio as deleted, like vs tried to load them.

How does VS2015 know not to show the 'bin' or 'obj' directories?